# Bluetooth Low Energy not working as expected on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm working on a distributed system which uses Bluetooth Low Energy to locate their users in a building. So far, we are using Android phones as peripheral devices to advertise different information in different meeting rooms.

Everything seems to be working fine but we found an issue with a Samsung S5 (SM-G900M) which is finding our advertisements (We are using ScanFilters to detect the peripheral devices) but the ScanRecord comes with empty or null values. The same code is working fine on a Pixel and Samsung S7.

This is our advertisement code:

```
private AdvertiseData createFMPAdvertiseData() {
    AdvertiseData.Builder builder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    builder.addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("d0acdb90-745a-42a9-8e4d-9de4fb9342dc")));
    return builder.build();
}

private static AdvertiseSettings createAdvSettings(boolean connectable, int timeoutMillis) {
    AdvertiseSettings.Builder builder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
    builder.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED);

    // Connectable true
    builder.setConnectable(connectable);
    builder.setTimeout(timeoutMillis);
    builder.setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH);
    return builder.build();
} 

mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(
                createAdvSettings(true, 0),
                createFMPAdvertiseData(),
                mAdvertiseCallback);
```

This is our scanning code:

```
public ScanSettings createScanSettings() {
        ScanSettings.Builder builder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
        builder.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH | ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST);
        builder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
        builder.setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE);

        return builder.build();
    }

    public void setCallbacks() {
        // Device scan callback.
        mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "RSSI" + result.getRssi());
                BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                Log.i(TAG, "Device " + device.getAddress() + ", Callback type: " + callbackType);
                ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();
                Log.i(TAG, "uuid data" + record.getServiceData());
                Log.i(TAG, "bytes" + byteArrayToHex(record.getBytes()));
                UUID uuid = record.getServiceUuids().get(0).getUuid();
                Log.i(TAG, "uuid" + record.getServiceUuids());
```

The Samsung S5 is running Android 6.0.1. 
Any help will be much appreciated.